# Seaborn diverging palette: fix mid and end-points

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to visualise value negative and positive values with seaborn, where negative values become blue with increasing magnitute and positive values orange. In particular, I need 0 to be guaranteed to be white.

My idea was to use:

```
sns.diverging_palette(260, 30, s=100, center='light', as_cmap=True)
```

but the [manual](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.diverging_palette.html) does not state that it guarantees a certain midpoint. Is there a way for me to fix it? E.g.

```
sns.diverging_palette(260, 30, s=100, center='light', mid_value=0, as_cmap=True)
```

and does this guarantee that `-c` and `c` have the same saturation (albeit different hues)?

Comment: Most certainly it's not configurable here as some plots may have a value from 0 to 100 then in that case diverging mid will be 50. And in seaborn middle/center value is passed from plot function itself.

Answer (score 0):

A colormap just maps values in range [0., 1.] to the range of colors. In your example 0 maps to blue, 1 maps to orange and 0.5 the midpoint maps to white.

So the question is actually how the range of your values is mapped to [0., 1.]. If we use seaborn heatmap plot as an example then by default it maps minimum value to 0 and maximum value to 1. And the average of minimum and maximum values will map to white color. So if the absolute values of minimum and maximum aren't equal then 0 won't be white like you want.

But you can override this mapping by supplying `vmin` and `vmax` keyword arguments to the heatmap - values to anchor the colormap. If you do `vmin=-C, vmax=C` where C is some positive number then that guarantees a white zero.

Here's an example plot of data skewed towards positive values. Default version on the left does not have a white zero. Version on the right fixes this by using `vmin` and `vmax` kwargs.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

data = np.random.randn(10,10) + 0.5
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,4), facecolor='w')
pal = sns.diverging_palette(260, 30, s=100, center='light', as_cmap=True)

sns.heatmap(data=data, cmap=pal, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('0 is not white')

vmax = np.abs(data).max()
sns.heatmap(data=data, cmap=pal, vmin=-vmax, vmax=vmax, ax=ax[1])
ax[1].set_title('Now it is!')
```

[image: two heatmap plots for comparison]